# Why is my ListView with ArrayAdapter not scrollable?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm struggling with getting a ListView to be able to scroll. As far as I have read it should be OK to have a ListView inside of a LinearLayout so why is it not scrolling?

This is the layout

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/tab3" />

    <include layout="@layout/tab1" />                 


</FrameLayout>
```

And here is where I fill it up with stuff..

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Download/");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayadp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_files);

for (File file : listOfFiles) {
    if (file.isFile()) {
        String extension = "";
        String filename = file.getName();
        int i = filename.lastIndexOf('.');
        if (i > 0) {
            extension = filename.substring(i+1);
        }               
        if(extension.equalsIgnoreCase("wav")){
            arrayadp.add(filename);
        }
    }
}
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
listView.setAdapter(arrayadp);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `orientation` attribute is necessary for a `LinearLayout`.  You'll need to set this to either `horizontal` or `vertical`, even if the `LinearLayout` only has one child.  I think this may be the cause of your issue; I've forgotten orientation many times and it can cause many weird problems with how your Views are displayed and behave.  You may also want to consider not using a `FrameLayout` as your root view here, as having a `FrameLayout` with multiple children can make it very difficult to get them laid out properly. Consider a `LinearLayout` if you want your three children in a horizontal or vertical row.

Answer (score 0):

it is ok to put a listview in a linearLayout.

it is not ok to set the height of the listView to be wrap_content, as listView contains a lot of items, all have dynamic size and number.

google has talked about this on [**this lecture**](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html) . please watch it all. it might help you with other things too.

Answer (score 0):

This problem because your root layout is a FrameLayout.

Insert linearlayout how root

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/tab3" />

    <include layout="@layout/tab1" />                 


</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```